# Is it possible to change the types of array values in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, floating-point

I'm retrieving data from a MySQL table. This data comes as string values and I would prefer to work with floating-point numbers. Here is what I'm doing:

```
$array_duracao = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(dt)/0.01666667 AS mysum FROM afunda_eleva");
$array_duracao->execute();
$result3 = $array_duracao->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$duracao_afunda_eleva[] = $result3;
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($duracao_afunda_eleva);$i++)
{
    $duracao_afunda_eleva1[]=settype($duracao_afunda_eleva[$i],"float");
}
```

When I call `var_dump($duracao_afunda_eleva1)`, it displays the following:

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> float(1) 
    [1]=> float(1) 
    [2]=> float(1) 
}
```

And when I call `var_dump($duracao_afunda_eleva)`, it displays this:

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(9) "3.6599993" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(9) "7.0199986" 
    } 
    [2]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(9) "1.3799997"
    } 
}
```

How can I change array values from strings to floating-point numbers?

Comment: Read the documentation of `settype`, especially the `RETURN VALUES` section.

Comment: try accessing the `0` array key from `$duracao_afunda_eleva[$i]` : `$duracao_afunda_eleva1[] = settype($duracao_afunda_eleva[$i][0],"float");`

Comment: You generally don't need to coerce types in PHP. It will automatically convert strings to numbers when you use them in mathematical expressions. And if it has a decimal point, it will convert them to floats.

Comment: The other problem is you're treating `$duracao_afunda_eleva` as a 1-D array, but it's a 2-D array. The strings are in the second dimension.

Comment: @barmar i'm trying to use these values with jpgraph, and it keeps returning me that  " Either X or Y data arrays contains non-numeric values" so i think the problem might be in the array terms, or am I wrong?

Comment: Hmm, and there's a clear mistake from me, that array is supposed to be 1-D. i'll see why it's 2D, then try some of the stuff mentioned here. Thanks u all!

Comment: It's 2-D because `fetch` returns an array, and you're pushing that array onto another array, so it becomes the 2nd dimension.

Comment: It's 2D because `$duracao_afunda_eleva1[] = ...` should be `$duracao_afunda_eleva1 = ...` since the result is already an array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change

```
$duracao_afunda_eleva1[]=settype($duracao_afunda_eleva[$i],"float");
```

to

```
$duracao_afunda_eleva1[]=floatval($duracao_afunda_eleva[$i]);
```

Comment: There's a type actually? Are duracao_afunda_eleva1 and duracao_afunda_eleva supposed to be the same variable? One has a `1` at the end, the other doesn't.

Comment: Oh, you're trying to convert an array into a float.

Your logic is kinda broken.

Comment: This:
`$duracao_afunda_eleva[] = $result3;`
should be:
`$duracao_afunda_eleva = $result3;`

Comment: not really, Hamza Kubba, cause i'm populating the array, it's inside a loop actually. But i've just seen some mistakes from me on the code, that returned me an undesired array dimension. I'll see what's going on so i'll try the answers. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As I see from `var_dump($duracao_afunda_eleva)` - `$duracao_afunda_eleva` is a multidimensional array. So if you want to typecast values you should do it with array values and not with array itself, your code should be (thanks to @Barmar):

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($duracao_afunda_eleva); $i++) {
    $duracao_afunda_eleva1[] = floatval($duracao_afunda_eleva[$i][0]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, there's something weird, this array shouldn't be multidimensional, i'll see what's going on, and try to get what i need. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
$float = (float) "1.234";
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/I6wsAl